# How to link a native library in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I want to create a react player using IJKplayer for iOS (https://github.com/Bilibili/ijkplayer).

I have gone through https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html#content.

I have the bridge files for IJKPLayer but the app is not able to find the native module.

Comment: Can you please post what the exact error message is?

Comment: Make sure you're executing `react-native run-ios` after you linked the library.

Comment: undefined is not an object (evaluating IJKPlayerManager.start)

Comment: I think its not able recognise IJKPlayer as nativemodule. @Eldelshell yes i ran react-native run-ios